# Is there a way to provide an Android app for testing without giving my client an apk or the code?

Tags: android, testflight

I have made an application ordered by a client, and I want to send it for testing. But I don't want to give him the code or the APK. How can provide the app for testing (Uploading online or something), without him receiving the code/apk?

Thanks!

Comment: So you are basically asking how to give your client the application without giving him the application? He/she cannot install and test it without the APK or the source files.

Comment: I think the TestFlight for iOS does that. Well, if you put it that way is sounds silly, but i want to take any measures to prevent my client from stealing the app and not giving me the money.

Comment: I never dared to touch iOS development. As far as I know, Android does not provide any such tools. Android is meant to be a free and open platform without any third-party restrictions. You could possibly use a remotely-controlled Android emulator to show off your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run the app on an emulated device and invite your client to a screen cast. This way they get an impression of the app but not the code.

The other (much more unreliable) option would be to rely on [ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) (to make code stealing harder) and a big red splash-screen saying "demo preview" (to prevent your client from distributing the app).

Comment: I'll enable ProGuard then! Thanks alot for the help!

Comment: ok, but be careful - it does not prevent code stealing, it only increases the effort. To check the result you should decompile your app yourself (a google search should reveal the necessary tools for that)

Comment: Ok! Well, the client trusted me and sent me money in advance, so I should offer some trust as well. Thanks again!